# Adding plugin to sidebar file in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

So im in the middle of creating a site with WordPress but now Im stuck at the sidebars.
In sidebar.php-file I have added some text and CSS rules as a test and they are shown at the site as a sidebar. However, I want to show the forum's latest posts in this sidebar instead.
Im using a plugin called "tt post viewer". I tested it out on a page at the site and it shows me the latest post.
But im not sure what code I should add to the sidebar.php-file so that the plugin print the latest post at the sidebar.
And if it's possible?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tt-post-viewer/

Would be grateful if anyone could help me out.

Thanks!

yours sincerely, Winterwind

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add code to the sidebar. Make sure your sidebar is wdiget-ready and just drag and drop the widget in the Wordpress Backend into your sidebar.

Comment: I have dragged it to the sidebar in the backend but its still dont pop up at the frontend. Do I need to add any code?

Comment: Did you create the theme on your own? If yes, is the sidebar widget ready? If you downloaded a theme, what's its name?

Comment: I've created the theme myself. And I got the sidebar section in dashboard. And I have created a sidebar.php-file which containts som lorem ipsum and CSS rules.

Comment: You need to widgetize your theme by adding some code to the function.php. See more details here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes